# Editing existing word File with MS Build output

Tags: c#, xml, msbuild

I am using msbuild to run an .proj file which reads the file name and version from a folder.  I wish to extract all the output onto an existing word file at specific locations.  For this I need to pass the file path along with text, cell position, table position, row position and overwrite parameters.

Any Ideas as to how to proceed??

Appreciate your help.

Thank you,
yank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seem to be Xml-Logger implementations which allow targeting MS-Word format coming with CC.Net.

A more complex solution would be to create your own specific logger - which is what you will need if you want to control how the document is updated (not just created new with every build).

A little less complex approach would be to `Exec` a powershell or vbscript to which you can pass the parameters needed.

A third way would be to use an existing Xml-Logger and do an Xsl transform into your word document.